# Installing r dependencies in Linux system?

Tags: linux, r

I'm trying to install a R package I received from directly from the developer in its *.tar.gz form. But the command:

```
install.packages("~/Path/to/the/file/package.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

gives

```
Installing package into ‘/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies ‘NetIndices’, ‘limSolve’, ‘diagram’ are not available  for package ‘package’
* removing ‘/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/package’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘/home/path/to/the/file/Package/package.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I get the dependencies along with the package? I have tried using dependencies=TRUE in install.packages to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set `repos` to `NULL` dependencies cannot be resolved. Try to install dependencies first:

```
install.packages(
    c("NetIndices", "limSolve", "diagram"), 
    repos="https://cran.rstudio.com" # or other CRAN mirror
)
```

and then install source package.

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing a tar.gz you have to install them yourself, or you can try Dirk's littler "little r" which is not an R package, but a Linux tool which among other things provides an install package tool which does what you want. There are Debian and Ubuntu packages.